# PHP Error Gathering Database Information

Tags: php, sql

Hi I have the following code below in a php file

```
 global $server, $mysqlusername, $mysqlpassword, $db;
 $conn = new mysqli($server, $mysqlusername, $mysqlpassword, $db);


function getCategories() {
global $conn;
$categories = array();

$sql = "SELECT categoryName FROM reportcategorys";
$maincat = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $maincat->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    // do something with the $row
    array_push($categories, $row);
}
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM reportsubcategorys";
$subcats = $conn->query($sql1);

// Loop through sub categories and append to parent array
while($row = $subcats->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $parent = $row['categoryName'];
    $name =   $row['subCategoryName'];

    // Append subcategory name as child to the parent category
    for ($i=0; $i<count($categories); $i++) {
        if ($categories[$i]['categoryName'] == $parent) {
            array_push($categories[$i], $name);
        }
    }
}
//print_r($categories);
return $categories;    
}
```

It is giving me an error message saying

**"Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in"**

Any idea what may be causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that your query has not executed properly.

`mysqli->query()` will return a boolean value `FALSE` if the query has not been executed properly, else it will return a `mysqli_result` object. So after every query, before calling fetch_array() method, check the result of the query. Something like this.

```
$maincat = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
```

or

```
$maincat = $conn->query($sql);
if(!$maincat){
    echo $conn->error;
}
```

Also, when you established your connection with the database, check if the connection was error-free.

```
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: having followed your instructions, its now telling me that no database has been selected

Comment: Then check your $db variable that you have used while establishing the connection. It's probably an invalid database or it's an empty string.    Echo the value of $db to see if it's empty.

Comment: Yeah, that is most of the issue resolved, it has expanded a little since then but its a different issue. Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using fetch_array for any reason in particular?

Try it like this one...

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* verificar la conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Conexión fallida: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* obtener array asociativo */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
    }

    /* liberar el resultset */
    $result->free();
}

/* cerrar la conexión */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: and you should probably check this link too http://us2.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: I will read this and see if it is better to not use the fetch_array